# How to 'startx' from Single User Mode?

Tags: macos, startup, x11, xquartz

I usually run dwm inside Xquartz on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8. But is there a way to boot into Safe Mode (or a console), then `startx` or `xinit`, skipping Aqua? I'd like to boot directly into X11.